# Aparecer as DIVS de apenas categoria selecionada

Tags: jquery, html, css

Olá,

Estou tendo um problema e não consigo achar a solução, pelo fato de ser algo comum na internet, acredito que não esteja procurando da forma correta.

Gostaria de selecionar as divs que iram ficar a mostra.
Ex:
Tenho vários produtos (cada um em uma div), quando carrego a página, mostra todos, porém, logo em cima tem uns filtros, exemplo: 
TUDO - TIPO1 - TIPO2 - TIPO3
Ao clicar em uma das opções, mostraria apenas os produtos (divs) dessa categoria. 
Por exemplo, clico no TIPO1, some todas as divs e fica apenas os produtos da categoria TIPO1.

Espero que tenha consigo explicar corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi! Sabendo aplicar, creio que esta seja uma excelente solução: O [Isotope Menu](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) faz exatamente isso de uma forma fluida e responsiva. Creio que para apresentar produtos, seria uma boa escolha.

Abaixo está exemplificado como no Codepen.

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js


// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    symbol: '.symbol',
    number: '.number parseInt',
    category: '[data-category]',
    weight: function(itemElem) {
      var weight = $(itemElem).find('.weight').text();
      return parseFloat(weight.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ''));
    }
  }
});

// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match(/ium$/);
  }
};

// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});

// bind sort button click
$('#sorts').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
  $grid.isotope({
    sortBy: sortByValue
  });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- button ---- */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em;
  background: #EEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2));
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8CF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}


/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.button-group .button:first-child {
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}

.button-group .button:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}


/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}


/* clear fix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
}

.element-item>* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali {
  background: #F00;
  background: hsl( 0, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.alkaline-earth {
  background: #F80;
  background: hsl( 36, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.lanthanoid {
  background: #FF0;
  background: hsl( 72, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.actinoid {
  background: #0F0;
  background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.transition {
  background: #0F8;
  background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.post-transition {
  background: #0FF;
  background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.metalloid {
  background: #08F;
  background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.diatomic {
  background: #00F;
  background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.halogen {
  background: #F0F;
  background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.noble-gas {
  background: #F08;
  background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<h1>Isotope - filtering &amp; sorting</h1>
<h2>Filter</h2>
<div id="filters" class="button-group"> <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".transition">transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="numberGreaterThan50">number > 50</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="ium">name ends with &ndash;ium</button>
</div>

<h2>Sort</h2>
<div id="sorts" class="button-group"> <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-by="original-order">original order</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="name">name</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="symbol">symbol</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="number">number</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="weight">weight</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-by="category">category</button>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Olhei o site e o código que você sugeriu, é exatamente o que eu quero, porém, achei um pouco complicado o código, queria algo mais simples. Só que vi o código rapidamente, irei analisar e verificar assim que chegar em casa e ter mais tempo.

Comment: @RafaelDantas De nada! Mas se você analisar com cuidado o que eu botei aqui, você vai acabar percebendo que não é nenhum bicho de sete cabeças. O CSS é ignorável nesse caso. A parte mais complicada é aprender a conectar o JS e o HTML, mas você pode ver que tudo é uma questão com os `data-filters` e classes. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: Cheguei em casa agora, vou tentar ver se consigo fazer com ele.

Comment: Dei uma olhada em todo o código, consegui editar e resolver meu problema com ele. Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: @RafaelDantas Nada! Que bom que funcionou! :)

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi Bem, Acredito  o Codigo a baixo irá ajudar

```html
<html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class = "Produto" data-tipo="TP1" >
  Tipo1
  </div>
  <div class = "Produto" data-tipo="TP1">
  Tipo1
  </div>
  <div class = "Produto " data-tipo="TP2">
  Tipo2
  </div>
  <div class = "Produto " data-tipo="TP3">
  Tipo3
  </div>
  <div class = "Produto" data-tipo="TP3" >
  Tipo3
  </div>
  
  <div id = "Rst">
  Reset
  </div>
  
  <script>
  $("body").on('click','.Produto',function(){
 var produtoSlcionado = $(this).data('tipo');
 $(".Produto").hide();
 $(".Produto[data-tipo='"+produtoSlcionado+"']").show();
  });
  
  $("body").on('click','#Rst',function(){
 $(".Produto").show();
  });
  
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, seria isso mesmo, porém queria que mostrasse através do click em um menu, ou seja, ao invés de clicar na própria div, clicar em um menu e as divs se "organizarem"

Comment: Voce pode utilizar a mesma logica do Click na Div, para um Click em um Menu. o Menu é um Button, link, ou div?

Comment: Então, tentei desenhar para explicar, com as palavras não estou sendo muito bom kk 
![imagem de exemplo](http://rdcreative.com.br/Exemplo.jpg)